# Finding a mentor

Tags: web, learning, photography-basics

I'm beginning photography and sometimes I find it very difficult to rate my own work or to find answers to common basic problems...

Is there any websites/forums that allow people to get rating and advices on their pictures by other more experienced photographs ?

I don't think I can use photo.stackexchange.com to do this because, it's more of a "I got a problem / I got the solution"...

Any advices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Likely duplicate, but I would mention that finding (or even starting) a local photography meeetup/club is a great way to meet other shooters. They often host photo critiques either online or in person -- in my experience people who know each other in real life tend to be a lot more polite with each other on line as well :-)

Comment: Oops, yeah seems a dupplicate ! Sorry 'bout that ! Thanks to everybody who answered anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the main page isn't a good place for critique since it's a Q/A site, the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography) is reasonably active and is a great place for asking for critiques and more discussion oriented questions that don't fit on the main site.

Comment: Yeah, but it only has about 3-4 active users over the past year. Not that you four aren't great, but it's not exactly full of contributors either.

Comment: Ehh, it's been a little more active lately.  There's about 5 core people, but overall I'd say we see probably 12 to 20 pass through in a month.  On the downside, it isn't a wide selection, but on the upside, it also means you get a consistent community that gets to know you.  That and I want to pimp it to be more active. :)

Comment: I'll give the chat a go but being in a different time zone (Switzerland) I guess I'll have some troubles finding awakend people when I post my messages :)

Comment: @AndyM - I think we may actually have more Europeans in the chat than we have people from the Americas, so you might be surprised.

Comment: I did asked for some comments on one of my picture and got great advices! I'll try and spend more time around the chat :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Flickr I recommend you [Critique2](http://www.flickr.com/groups/critique2/)

About the group:

> Critique 2 is all about member participation. Think of this group as a workshop, where you can display your work to other photographers of all levels of experience and skill, for discussion of its strengths and weaknesses, suggestions for improvement and hints for overcoming shortcomings.